# Format the string which is used as binding to a TextBlock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a TextBlock in the MainWindow.

I have a binding for it as below:

```
<TextBlock Name="LogMessageBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding BindingString} HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And in the code I have:

```
public string BindingString{ get; set; }
```

Now the problem I have is that I want to have colors for the text that I set the BindingString to:

```
BindingString = "This is a text String"
```

I want the output to be shown as

[image]

I can do this if I directly access the TextBlock as

```
LogMessageBox.Inlines.Add( new Run(message)) { Foreground = color });
```

and split the string message.

How can i do this by binding such that i can set color/format of different portion of string?

Comment: How do you want to define the colors? Inline in the data string? Pattern matching? Something else?

Comment: I would like to define inline in the data string.